# Why c# converts a number with commas or a currency sign to Integer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have textbox on an aspx page and on textbox text change event I noticed that even if the user enters 2,000 or $2,000, it's automatically converted to 2000. That caught me off guard as I thought I was supposed to remove the $ sign and commas from the number before I assign it to the integer variable. Something similar like below

```
int ID = txtID.text.Replace(",","").Replace("$", "");
```

Is this a feature introduced recently or has this been since c# 1.0?

Comment: Take a look at `Int.Parse` or `Int.TryParse`

Comment: What does the rendered html look like?  Might it be emitting an input of type `number`?

Comment: `txtID.text` does not look like C# code from an asp.net forms? what does txtID.text show to you?

Comment: Id of textbox is txtID. How is that not asp.net c# code? I'm getting the textbox value back successfully.
<asp:Textbox runat="server" id="txtId"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: `.text` is not C#/.Net style of naming... Possibly third party control... You really need to post code that demonstrates problem and not some random (and really questionable due to ignoring proper decimal separators) code.

Comment: int ID =  int.parse(txtID.text.Replace(",","").Replace("$", ""));

Answer (score 1):

You should use decimal.TryParse in this format:

```
decimal result = 0;

Decimal.TryParse(text, 
    NumberStyles.Currency, 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
    out result);
```

Be sure that you are choosing correct Culture !

[Check this demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Aeqw0P)

Comment: The question is "why is the value is *automatically* converted", not how to convert it

Comment: @Rob I'm giving the op how to make his code work. Also what he wrote in the question is not compile code. He want to convert implicit string to int, this is not going to happen. Here is an article what can be converted implicit to int :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx . So like summary I don't see how he has such output when the example code is not working !

Comment: @mybirthname Thanks for the reply. Maybe I didn't explain myself well. The question is not about converting textbook value to int. C# is already doing that if I enter a valid int like 3200 for example. The thing I'm trying to understand is even if I enter $3,200 in the textbook, c# is converting the textbook value to int.

Comment: @mybirthname It makes sense why c# would automatically do that, but I just want to know  if this feature existed since c# 1.0?

Comment: @user3587180 this conversion is not done automatically. Check if you are not using custom control for this textboxes. Also could you share the aspx part of this control ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following:

```
double _amt = double.Parse (txtID.text.Replace(",",String.Empty).Replace("$", String.Empty));
```

Correspondingly, to display the `_amt` as string, use `"C"` currency format specifier, like:

```
string _strAmt = _amt.ToString("C");
```

Hope this will work for you.

A little clarification to your question: in the example you have shown

```
int ID = txtID.text.Replace(",","").Replace("$", "")
```

the system is implicitly trying to cast the number presented as string to the `int ID` var as specified. Also (quote): "*2,000 or $2,000 it's automatically converted to 200*" - is it really 200 or 2000?

Best regards,

Comment: The question is "why is the value is *automatically* converted", not how to convert it

Comment: @alex My bad I had a typo. It should be 2000.

Comment: It's OK. Above you can find the answer to your original Question, plus a sample code snippet included to demonstrate the right (explicit) type conversion recommended for use rather than reliance on the numerous intricacies of C# implicit type casting. Best regards,

Answer (score -1):

answer is

```
var id = txtID.text.Replace(",", "");
var id = txtID.text.Replace("$", "");

int result = Convert.ToInt32(id);
```

2,000 => 2000

Comment: Please re-read the question. The question is asking about why/how a value is being *automatically converted*, not how to convert the value.

Comment: Besides that, your code won't compile, as you're re-defining your `id` variable in the second line.